# String identifier method calls on specific instantiations of a plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, methods, plugins

So I have ran into a bit of a mental block with my plugin interface. Say you have a plugin that when instantiated on a jQuery selector, iterates over the selection and instantiates a new object/instance for each of the selected elements. Assuming this is the html we have to work with:

```
<p class='p1'> This is just a simple test paragraph </p>
<p class='p2'> And here is another to show variety! </p>
```

And this is how the plugin is being instantiated:

```
$('p').pluginName();
```

Now, both of those p tags have been passed into the plugin init, each of them will receive their own instance of the plugin. For sure I could use the classes as a more specific identifier but roll with me here. Assuming I now wanted to use a string identifier to call into the plugin to do something as it's API allows like so:

```
$('p').pluginName('set', 'some_style');
```

But I only want it to apply to `class p2` let's say, is there any way to provide the method call above with info regarding a specific instance. Or as I feel it more likely will be, Do I have to be more specific with my instantiations and method calls to get at the instances I want to effect?

I ask because, while on a small scale, going from one plugin call to two when instantiating wouldn't be so bad. But what if there were hundreds of elements that this plugin was going to operate on? I don't want to force a potential user to have to instantiate on every single element to retain the ability to call into those instances easily if I can avoid that.

Some other info...

Every element is associated with a `data-cl-uid` attribute to hold an ID unique to that element/instance as well as reference to some state stuff. Beyond that, it also serves as a grouping mechanic, so two instances with the same ID will both be affected when one or the other has something applied to it. I feel like my design has me backed into a corner but I am not an experienced enough plugin designer to find a clear path forward.

Hopefully this gives some context, this is the code that handles the plugin itself and what the plugin does based on what's passed to it, aka what happens when you use string identifiers to call into an instance or group of instances:

```
  $.fn[pluginName] = function (option) {
    var args = arguments;

    if (typeof option === 'object' || !option) {
      this.each(function() {
        if(!$.data(this, 'plugin_'+pluginName))
          $.data(this, 'plugin_'+pluginName, new Clicklight(this, option, args[1]));
        else {
          console.log('ERROR: Cannot create a duplicate object for ',this);
          return false;
        }
      });

    } else if (typeof option === 'string' && option in pubAPI) {
      this.each(function() {
        var instance = $.data(this, 'plugin_'+ pluginName);

        if (instance instanceof Clicklight && typeof instance[option] === 'function')
          instance[option].apply(instance, Array.prototype.slice.call(args, 1));
        else {
          console.log('ERROR: Internal error from \''+option+ '\'');
          return false;
        }
      });

    } else
      console.log('ERROR: No method found with name \''+option+ '\'');

    return this;
  }
```

Hopefully that is enough info to get my problem across and all the needed code to show where the problem exists. Any other info I would be happy to edit in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well after a lot more thought I found a solution to the problem. I decided to build a controller object that essentially acts as the mediator between the user and the instances. For every `$(SELECTOR).plugin()` that is executed, one controller will be made for that instance, every element in that selector will then be made a child and can be called on by the controller in a given instance. This coupled with the fact that the API now calls for mandatory ID's to be placed, it is extremely easy to grab any single instantiation and it's members while the actually instantiation process is still very simple and can even be a single line of code. I'll edit in my code when I have all the bugs worked out and a patter I like.